# Microsoft Excel - Exact Keyword search - (Search a keyword phrase from a group of comma separated keyword phrases )

Tags: excel, search, find, string-matching, keyword-search

Problem statement:
I have a column in excel with contains multiple keyword phrases (comma separated). I want to exclude all the rows which does not contain the word "hello" only *(case-insensitive)*

Input:

| Within Text | Exclude |
| --- | --- |
| Hello there,hello,welcome |  |
| hello there |  |
| welcome |  |
| hello |  |
| how are you,hello |  |

Output:

| Within Text | Exclude |
| --- | --- |
| Hello there,hello,welcome | Yes |
| hello there | No |
| welcome | No |
| hello | Yes |
| how are you,hello | Yes |

Tried solution: (under column Exclude)
=IF(OR(search(",hello,",J3)>0,search(",hello",J3)>0,search("hello,",J3)>0),"Yes","No")

Comment: why output for "hello there" is "No" ?

Comment: As per the requirement,  "hello" and "hello there" are two different phrases. The expectation is to only exclude the rows which contains the phrase "hello" only

Comment: your "Tried solution" seem to be ok.. (is was not mentioned in the question..) d u get any error ? | Hint : try have a look on `iferror()` functon